# Python: merging dictionaries while merging some keys but not others?

Tags: python

I am trying to format movie listings from a number of cinemas. Most show many of the same movies but at different times. I'm working from a .csv.

Here is a sample after importing and creating listings as dictionaries:

```
holygrail : {
    rating : pg,
    cinema : regal,
    times : 1, 3, 5
    }

holygrail : {
    rating : pg,
    cinema : amc,
    times : 2, 4, 6
    }
```

and I'm looking for an out put like this:

```
holygrail : {
    rating: pg,
    cinema1 : {cinema : regal, times : 1, 3, 5},
    cinema2 : {cinema : amc, times : 2, 4, 6}
    }
```

or

```
holygrail : {
    rating: pg,
    regal : {times : 1, 3, 5},
    amc : {times : 2, 4, 6}
    }
```

It occurs to me I could make cinemas instances of a class but not sure how to integrate that in the dictionaries.

Comment: One option, you could look into using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Do you literally want a string of numbers for the times or do you want a list of integers? For example, `[1,3,5]`? Could you also include your raw csv? It is likely simpler to go directly from there.

Comment: also, note that while you can do it from the dictionaries, you started with a csv. it might be better to convert the csv into the desired dictionary instead of the intermediate step.

Comment: +1 to the first comment. `defaultdict` is always a go-to for aggregating data into a single dictionary. Probably I'd structure it like `holygrail : { ..., theatres : { regal : { times : [1, 3, 5] }, ...} }` where `theatres` is a `defaultdict`. Though the commenter directly above makes a good point as well.

Comment: Can you show the csv? https://bpaste.net/ ?

Comment: @rafl23 The numbers aren't integers. Actually, they will be times: 2 PM, etc., so strings. csv looks like `AMC Lake Square 12,Ralph Breaks the Internet,4.5,10:30a | 1:15p | 4:00p | 6:45p`

Comment: I can see defaultdict is a better way to build the dictionaries but I'm still unsure how to use that to merge some key:value pairs without merging others.